# Clarifying 3D SUMIF equation

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create a graph that shows days vs gallons of water usage for an apartment community that has 188 units. I have to download each units 30 day usage table into one excel file, so I end up with 188 excel files I have to combine to one. I have a macro that can combine and rename each sheet to the unit number based on the file name (ex. Unit 02101.xlsx). I'm using a 3D SUMIF equation because each unit does not have consistent read dates. The dates range from 1/17/2023-2/15/2023, and many sheets are missing dates within that range.

I followed the directions here: https://exceljet.net/formulas/sum-across-multiple-worksheets-with-criteria
and I created a named range for the list of units as well.

The equation I end up with looks like = SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&Sheets&"'!"&"A2"A22),A3,INDIRECT("'"&Sheets&"'!"&"C2:C22")))

When I first tested this equation with a few sheets, everything added up correctly. However, with over 200 sheets, it's not adding all adding up. The resulting graph should look first like a line trending up, almost exponentially, and then dramatically go down on a single day and fall flat for the days after because of a maintenance project. Even with dates missing, it shouldn't impact the graph too much because the increase and decrease in water usage was intense. In addition, I know it's not adding up because the total amount over the 30 days is half of what the community was billed.

Here is the image of the summary sheet: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoShG.png)
Here is an image of a unit's individual usage sheet: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozp9U.png)

Any ideas on what I am missing here? I checked all the sheets and they are named/formatted correctly. It seems like the equation is able to find all of them.

Comment: Your formula tells to sum only values where the date equals `A3` in the current sheet. Isn't this supposed to be a range?

Comment: I thought that that was the criteria, and the range is INDIRECT("'"&Sheets&"'!"&"C2:C22")

Comment: Yes that's correct, but the condition is one date. Is that intended?

Comment: Yes, I want to total the water consumption for that specific date in all 188 unit sheets.

Comment: But with given info, how are we to check for correctness? Also, indirect is known to slow files down. Is the calculation done when you're checking? Maybe VBA is a better alternative?

Comment: Or since you write that you use a macro to create sheets from the data, why not write them all to one sheet (and write the unit away in a new column. That will make the formula much easier/faster

Comment: I'd take a different approach.  One would be to create a table that has the entire range of dates on one axis, and the entire range of unit numbers on the other.  I would especially consider this with Excel O365.  The idea is to get all the data points you know in one table using one set of formulas (or Power Query), and then separately have logic that calculates the results.  Whenever an Excel solution gets too complicated, then separate the gathering and organizing of the data from the processing of the result.

Comment: ...cont... The other approach would be to get the data into a normalized data table (again, could be Power Query) so that you have on giant list of data points.  Each row has a date, a unit number, and a usage, and use pivot tables to generate the report.